# Can I publish Аccess database sharepoint 2010

Tags: office-integration, office-web-apps

There is one Access database, which consists of a single table (r_data), reports, queries, and VBA modules.
VBA modules can change the structure of the table r_data.
VBA modules can also write data to the table r_data from another database.

Can such Access database be published on SharePoint, using Access Services?

I suspect not. Please explain to me why.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried it myself but after a bit of research I can say

Yes you can look at links below,

[publish-your-access-database-to-sharepoint](http://blogs.technet.com/b/hub/archive/2010/11/08/publish-your-access-database-to-sharepoint.aspx)

[Video for publishing to sharepoint using Access](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq-tDuPfgZc)

**EDIT**

Since your updating Database outside sharepoint using VBA module, so it shouldn't interrupt sharepoint publishing it, you might come across few issues while publishing tho, but if I was you, I would actually try it myself first :)